# Postgres "ERROR: XX000: cache lookup failed for type 0 LOCATION: format_type_extended, format_type.c:128"?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, enums, mysql-fdw

updated.
I created a test table in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE sizes (
     size ENUM('small', 'medium', 'large')
;
insert into sizes values ('small'),('medium'),('medium');
```

In Postgresql,

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE sizes("size" text) SERVER test_server OPTIONS (dbname 'enumtest', table_name 'sizes');
```

Then can do `select * from sizes;` without error.
My question is
can I define multiple data type in postgresql like

```
DO $$BEGIN 
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type WHERE typname = 'size_t')  
    THEN CREATE TYPE size_t AS enum('small','medium','large');
  END IF;
END$$;
```

instead of ENUM use test just like a test? I tried replacing not work.

```
DO $$BEGIN 
     IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type WHERE typname = 'size_t') 
       THEN CREATE TYPE size_t AS text; 
  END IF; 
END$$;
```

Or it there any way I can do so, so I can use `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA`?
Thank you very much!

Origial:
The problem is when I refresh materialized views or create materialized views with data. I got this kind of error.

```
ERROR:  XX000: cache lookup failed for type 0
LOCATION:  format_type_extended, format_type.c:128
```

I'm refreshing materialized views which selecting from foreign tables imported by mysql_fdw. The tables in MySQL database have columns with `enum` type. I did datatype set as noticed by PostgreSQL before importing foreign tables.

The data type in MySQL table is

```
brandCategory   enum('S1','S2','S3','T','(N/A)')
```

The code to create data type in PostgreSQL is

```
DO $$BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type
                  WHERE typname = 'brandcategory_t')
   THEN
      CREATE TYPE brandcategory_t
         AS enum('S1','S2','S3','T','(N/A)');
   END IF;
END$$;
```

Then importing foreign tables.

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA admin_testdb FROM SERVER mysql_server INTO public;
```

Alter the name of foreign table and create a materialized view.

```
ALTER TABLE"tbl_Brand" RENAME TO "tbl_Brand_v";
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "tbl_Brand" AS SELECT * FROM "tbl_Brand_v" WITH DATA;
```

Result of `\d "tbl_Brand_v"` is

```
                             Foreign table "public.tbl_Brand_v"
    Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default | FDW options 
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+-------------
 brandId       | integer                     |           | not null |         | 
 brandCode     | character varying(30)       |           |          |         | 
 brandName     | character varying(200)      |           |          |         | 
 brandCategory | brandcategory_t             |           |          |         | 
 brandRemark   | text                        |           |          |         | 
 brandActive   | smallint                    |           |          |         | 
 dtCreated     | timestamp without time zone |           |          |         | 
 personCreated | integer                     |           |          |         | 
 dtUpdated     | timestamp without time zone |           |          |         | 
 personUpdated | integer                     |           |          |         | 
 dtDeleted     | timestamp without time zone |           |          |         | 
 personDeleted | integer                     |           |          |         |
```

The result of `\dT+ brandcategory_t` is

```
                                           List of data types
 Schema |      Name       |  Internal name  | Size | Elements |  Owner   | Access privileges | Description 
--------+-----------------+-----------------+------+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------
 public | brandcategory_t | brandcategory_t | 4    | S1      +| postgres |                   | 
        |                 |                 |      | S2      +|          |                   | 
        |                 |                 |      | S3      +|          |                   | 
        |                 |                 |      | T       +|          |                   | 
        |                 |                 |      | (N/A)    |          |                   |
```

This is the stack trace when doing `select * from "tbl_Brand_v";`.

```
#0  errfinish (dummy=dummy@entry=0) at elog.c:414
#1  0x0000000000851fa8 in elog_finish (elevel=elevel@entry=20, fmt=fmt@entry=0x8963a0 "cache lookup failed for type
 %u") at elog.c:1376
#2  0x0000000000788acd in format_type_extended (type_oid=type_oid@entry=0, typemod=typemod@entry=-1, flags=flags@en
try=0) at format_type.c:151
#3  0x0000000000788b4c in format_type_be (type_oid=type_oid@entry=0) at format_type.c:330
#4  0x000000000077f289 in enum_in (fcinfo=<optimized out>) at enum.c:46
#5  0x0000000000855747 in OidFunctionCall3Coll (functionId=functionId@entry=3506, collation=collation@entry=0, arg1
=40290088, arg2=arg2@entry=0, arg3=arg3@entry=18446744073709551615) at fmgr.c:1471
#6  0x00007ff6e0eab16c in mysql_convert_to_pg (pgtyp=<optimized out>, pgtypmod=<optimized out>, column=<optimized o
ut>) at mysql_query.c:160
#7  0x00007ff6e0ead52c in mysqlIterateForeignScan (node=<optimized out>) at mysql_fdw.c:652
#8  0x000000000062eccb in ForeignNext (node=node@entry=0x254b8c0) at nodeForeignscan.c:54
#9  0x000000000060c9fa in ExecScanFetch (recheckMtd=0x62eb80 <ForeignRecheck>, accessMtd=0x62ec30 <ForeignNext>, no
de=0x254b8c0) at execScan.c:95
#10 ExecScan (node=0x254b8c0, accessMtd=0x62ec30 <ForeignNext>, recheckMtd=0x62eb80 <ForeignRecheck>) at execScan.c
:145
#11 0x000000000060468a in ExecProcNode (node=0x254b8c0) at ../../../src/include/executor/executor.h:247
#12 ExecutePlan (execute_once=<optimized out>, dest=0x25fe9f0, direction=<optimized out>, numberTuples=0, sendTuple
s=true, operation=CMD_SELECT, use_parallel_mode=<optimized out>, planstate=0x254b8c0, estate=0x254b6b0) at execMain
.c:1723
#13 standard_ExecutorRun (queryDesc=0x2549430, direction=<optimized out>, count=0, execute_once=<optimized out>) at
 execMain.c:364
#14 0x0000000000746f1b in PortalRunSelect (portal=portal@entry=0x258d250, forward=forward@entry=true, count=0, coun
t@entry=9223372036854775807, dest=dest@entry=0x25fe9f0) at pquery.c:932
#15 0x00000000007482df in PortalRun (portal=<optimized out>, count=9223372036854775807, isTopLevel=<optimized out>,
 run_once=<optimized out>, dest=0x25fe9f0, altdest=0x25fe9f0, completionTag=0x7ffdbb422200 "") at pquery.c:773
#16 0x0000000000744287 in exec_simple_query (query_string=<optimized out>) at postgres.c:1145
#17 0x0000000000745552 in PostgresMain (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, dbname=<optimized out>, usernam
e=<optimized out>) at postgres.c:4182
#18 0x0000000000480571 in BackendRun (port=0x2549730) at postmaster.c:4358
#19 BackendStartup (port=0x2549730) at postmaster.c:4030
#20 ServerLoop () at postmaster.c:1707
#21 0x00000000006d8639 in PostmasterMain (argc=argc@entry=3, argv=argv@entry=0x2521280) at postmaster.c:1380
#22 0x00000000004813cf in main (argc=3, argv=0x2521280) at main.c:228
```

I expect the materialized view can be refreshed or created with data but got the error.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems that combine to produce that effect:

1. Bad enum data values.

   The enum type input function `enum_in` tries to convert the string it receives from MySQL to `brandcategory_t`.

   In line 159, this function checks

   ```js
   if (strlen(name) >= NAMEDATALEN)
   ```

   where `name` is the value received from MySQL.

   So there must be a row in the MySQL table that contains a string of more than 63 bytes for this enum value.

   (That assumes that mysql_fdw's code is correct and does what it says.)
2. A bug in mysql_fdw:

   Line 160 in `mysql_query.c` reads:

   ```js
   value_datum = OidFunctionCall3(typeinput, valueDatum, ObjectIdGetDatum(InvalidOid), Int32GetDatum(typemod));
   ```

   - The type input function called is `enum_in`, and if that function encounters an error, it tries to include the name of the enum type in the error message.
   - The enum type is the third argument of the `OidFunctionCall3` call, so it is `ObjectIdGetDatum(InvalidOid)`.
   - `InvalidOid` is 0, and `enum_in` understandably throws the error you see.

   You should report this bug to mysql_fdw.

Comment: Could you also look at the upmost updated part of the question please? Thank you very much!

Comment: If you use `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA`, you have no choice which data type you get (I think). Try `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE`. I don't know what mysql_fdw supports, I just explained your error message. Did you talk to the mysql_fdw folks?

Comment: I raised an issue in mysql_fdw, and found there was actually such issue since more than two years ago. Finally tried a way to work around, which is to alter foreign table tbl alter col type text; for all the enum type columns. Thank you very much! :)